# Purpose of subsequent use of OR and AND compound assignment operators on registers

Tags: c, embedded, compound-assignment

In C and C++ code, in particular that for embedded systems, I regularly stumble upon assignments that take the following shape:

```
A |= B;
A &= B;
```

Not sure if relevant, but A and B are registers here. See an example here:
http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Interrupt_Nesting_on_C28x#Example_Code
The following lines appear:

```
IER |= 0x002;
IER &= 0x002;
```

However, these *subsequent* assignments seem identical to the *single* assignment

```
A = B;
```

Except for the fact that, theoretically, the former can in some cases be interrupted between both lines, but this does not seem to play an important role in most codes.

Is there an advantage of using the former over the latter, or is there another difference that I fail to see?

Comment: The code you show and link to is for an embedded system. Setting and clearing bits might make different things happen in the hardware. So it's possible it is split up that way to trigger different hardware events.

Comment: Also, in C++ you have to consider things like operator overloading.

Comment: `IER` in your example is a processor register, so it may be used at each cycle. Maybe this is the reason.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - you should write that comment as an answer; it is correct, valid and generally useful to others who may be confused by the same examples

Comment: That close vote for "primarily opinion-based" reason is not valid.

Comment: You could provide some context otherwise this seems like a too broad question.

Comment: @2501 I think the link with the excerpt of the code is enough for the context.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs OP should explain that he/she is interested in that particular architecture. As the question and the tags stand, it appears that the question is about C and/or C++ in general, and the link serves only as a code source.

Comment: @2501 Well yes, I totally agree on this.

Comment: @Some programmer dude. Thanks. I did not consider that the fact I'm dealing with embedded systems is relevant. I will consider it part of the answer. The other part would then be related to distinguishing between variables and registers, I suppose?

Comment: Can those that vote for "primarily opinion based" elucidate their vote such that I can improve my question? It will be appreciated.

Comment: @JJMDriessen I have updated my answer with *distinguishing between variables and registers* part.

Comment: There is no "embedded C". And please don't add redundant information in the title, that's what the tags are for.

Comment: There is no guarantee the single assignment (resp. any other expression) will be atomic either.

Comment: `IER |= 0x002;
IER &= 0x002;` has a sequence point in between.  So the first will be done before the second.  Consider an alternative `IER &= 0x002;
IER |= 0x002;`.  The first pair insures `IER` has at least 1 bit set before clearing others.    The 2nd insures all bits are zero except _maybe_ one.  Then it sets a bit.  The second scenario prevents any interrupt (IER<-- Interrupt enable register), while the first always allows an interrupt.  If that interrupt was a debug handle, it would be hard to step through code in the 2nd case.

Answer (score 6):

Of course, sequence of two following commands:

```
A |= 0x02;
A &= 0x02;
```

Is identical to:

```
A = 0x02;
```

Unless the `A` is not a variable, but a hardware register. In this case you need to refer to the MCU/CPU (or mapped peripheral) manual to check why exactly this sequence is required.

---

UPDATE

**Variable vs Hardware register**

In the comments above, OP asked how to *distinguish between variables and registers*.

This is quite easy. All you need to do is to look at the definition. While typical variable would be defined as something like:

```
unsigned char A;
```

Hardware register definition will look similar to:

```
#define A (*(volatile uint16_t *)(0x1234))
```

Here, `A` is defined as a value of a hardware register, mapped to address at `0x1234`. Every microcontroller or CPU has it's own unique set of hardware registers, and it *will* vary not only between different kind of architectures and models, but also between different manufacturers. If the source code is not well documented, the only way to tell what particular hardware register is about is to look into hardware datasheet. Also, some advanced architectures can *map* hardware registers from some peripherals into CPU address space, so that it is possible to access hardware registers of external components in the same way.

Note the `volatile` keyword. From the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_(computer_programming)):

> This keyword prevents an optimizing compiler from optimizing away subsequent reads or writes and thus incorrectly reusing a stale value or omitting writes. Volatile values primarily arise in hardware access (memory-mapped I/O), where reading from or writing to memory is used to communicate with peripheral devices, and in threading, where a different thread may have modified a value.

Answer (score 1):

In case the variable is a hardware register, which seems to be the case, the variables are `volatile`. Writing a bit followed by clearing a bit, is then not the same thing as just writing a value.

Hardware registers don't always behave like plain RAM variables. It is not certain that writing a zero clears a bit. Flag and status registers in particular can have certain conditions, such as "this flag is cleared by writing to the bit, followed by a read to the register". In other cases, flags could be cleared by simply reading the register.

This is very common for flag/status registers user for serial communication peripherals such as SPI or UART.

Also, note that there's no guarantee that `A = B;` results in a single instruction. More likely it results in: "load B", "store B in A". If you need things to be atomic, you must always disassemble the code to see what you actually ended up with.

Answer (score 1):

There possibly are circumstances for hardware registers where certain bit sequences are necessary of have "special" behaviour, although it is hard to see what that might be in this particular instance.

Do not underestimate the probability of code you find on the Internet to be nonsense, even if it is from the chip vendor's site.  Looking at the documentation it seems likley that the author has read this:

[image]

and has been confused by the reference to OR IER/AND IER - they do enable and disable interrupts but so does the MOV IER instruction *atomically*. which is what the direct assignment will do.

There is a later example on that same page:

```
IER |= M_INT2;
IER &= MINT2;                         // Set "global" priority
```

Where the operands differ; so perhaps the author simply has a generalised pattern and is sticking with it.

Answer (score -2):

A |= 0x02;
is same as 
A = 0x02;

A &=0x2 stills equal to zero (A=0 assumption)

if both A and B are one byte value.But there are cases where it is not equal to one byte, in these scenario all of these operators have different properties.

I am taking example of 4-byte value.

A=0x12345600

A |= 0x2 equals  0x12345602
whereas 
A &= 0x2 equals  0x12345600
and
A = 0x2  equals  0x00000002

Comment: "A |= 0x02; is same as A = 0x02;"  Only if A is zero. There is nothing in the question indicating that this is the case. Also `0x12345600 & 0x2` gives 0.